# Move back issues from other projects

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I need your kindly support.

I have a big project in my redmine with a lot of subprojects in it.
More than 300 issues have been moved from this project to another subprojects by mistake. And I haven't got a chance to rescue it by hands directly from redmine. But I have a database dump which has been done before this accident. 
So, my question is - Can I compare table "issue" from right database with damaged database and move issues back? Or May be has any tools or methods to move back issues to right project?
Redmine version is 2.0.4. Database: PostgreSQL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**plan a:**
You can try to analyze table `issues` and find all issues which are move wrongly.
You know new project_id and you know approximately timestamps of changes. And write sql query (or use rails console) to undo action.
for example (code NOT tested!)

```
new_project_id = Project.find(ID).id # note that ID is project identificator not id of record!
timestamp = DateTime.parse('2013-10-30 12:20:45')
issues = Issue.where(project_id: new_project_id).where('updated_at > ? AND updated_at < ?', timestamp - 1.minute, timestamp + 1.minute)
# check that all selected issues must be updated!!!
issues.update_all(project_id: old_project_id) # note that old_project_id is correct id (integer value) of record in DB
```

**plan b:**
you can find all issue_id which have project_id in correct DB. And then apply SQL query to update project id to correct value for all issues `where id IN (issue_ids)`  on corrupted DB

```
# load correct DATABASE and start rails console
project = Project.find(OLD_ID) # note that OLD_ID is project identificator not id of record!
issue_ids = project.issue_ids
# save somewhere issue_ids
# load corrupted database and start rails console
issue_ids = [saved_array_of_ids_from_previous_step]
Issue.where(id: issue_ids).update_all(project_id: correct_project_id) # note that correct_project_id is correct id (integer value) of record in DB
```